# Interactive Python - solutions for relative imports

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

From [Python relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time):

- For a `from .. import` to work, the module's name must have at least as many dots as there are in the `import` statement.
- ... if you run the interpreter interactively ... the name of that interactive session is `__main__`
- Thus you cannot do relative imports directly from an interactive session

I like to use interactive Jupyter Notebook sessions to explore data and test modules before writing production code. To make things clear and accessible to teammates, I like to place the notebooks in an `interactive` package located alongside the packages and modules I am testing.

```
package/

    __init__.py

    subpackage1/

        __init__.py

        moduleX.py

        moduleY.py

        moduleZ.py

    subpackage2/

        __init__.py

        moduleZ.py

    interactive/
        __init__.py
        my_notebook.ipynb
```

During an interactive session in `interactive.my_notebook.ipynb`, how would you import other modules like `subpackage1.moduleX` and `subpackage2.moduleZ`?

Answer (score 4):

The solution I currently use is to append the parent package to `sys.path`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/.../package/")

import subpackage1.moduleX
import subpackage2.moduleZ
```

Comment: I think it would make more sense to add `package`'s parent directory to `sys.path`. This way you can always do `from package.subpackageN import moduleZ`