# Unable to 'relative import' a local Python library using a symbolic link

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, python-import, symlink

My project has two main folders: `sourceCode` and `lib`: [Highlighted file tree here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ebtp.png)

I'm working in `\sourceCode\mainFile.ipynb` and would like to import a library residing in `lib` called `modifiedLibrary`, which has an `__init__.py` file.

Currently, I'm using a symbolic link for [relative-importing](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html) the library. The symbolic link is located in `\sourceCode` and called `sym_link` with the following content:

```
../lib/modifiedLibrary/modifiedLibrary
```

*In the project, the library and the symbolic link have the **same name**.*

but when I import in python using

```
import modifiedLibrary
```

I receive `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modifiedLibrary'`

I understand that the same code functions on another device that I do not have access to right now, and I do not seem to find what the issue is.

I successfully included the needed library by:

1. changing the working directory temporarily to where the library's `__init__.py` is located,
2. importing the library
3. then reverting back to my original directory

but I would like to know what the issue is with the current symbolic link.

Windows 10 / Python 3.7.3 / Jupyter

[Relevant Question: Interactive Python - solutions for relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488860/interactive-python-solutions-for-relative-imports)

Comment: The relative import syntax you have shown is Python2 only. For Python3, use ``from  . import modifiedLibrary`` instead. Note that a notebook would not be run as part of a package (``sourceCode.__main__``) but a top-level script (``__main__``) - you cannot use relative imports at all.

Comment: This may be of relevance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50392363/5349916

Comment: @MisterMiyagi using `from . import modifiedLibrary` returns `ImportError: cannot import name 'modifiedLibrary' from '__main__' (unknown location)`. sourceCode only has an ipynb file, the symlink and some dataset.

Comment: As said, you cannot use relative imports at all. You may want to modify ``sys.path`` by preprending ``"\sourceCode"`` - this should allow an absolute import of your package. Properly installing it is much better for reproducibility, though.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to do more reading on importing in python 3 and what's new from python 2. I'm a bit new to the language.
Adding the library to the python path using `sys.path.append('C:/User/.../myProject/lib/modifiedLibrary/modifiedLibrary')` before executing `import modifiedLibrary` is fixing the issue for now. [Basic importing in python 3 tutorial here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-modules-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

The other solution I found, rather than changing the working directory temporarliy to include a local module, was to add the location of the module on my device to `sys.path` before importing it:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/user/myProject/../modifiedLibrary/')

import modifiedLibrary
```

It doesn't make use of the symbolic link but it seems to do the trick for now. Would be an issue when the code is shared and ran on another device.